# MVVMLight Event to Command with model as command parameter

Tags: c#, binding, uwp, mvvm-light

I've been trying to use MVVMLight's Event to Command feature to link commands in my ViewModel to events like TextChanged in a TextBox, for example. Thing is, in UWP, the Event to Command automatically assumes that the command parameter is the event args of the TextChanged. I don't want that, I want to send a model as the command parameter, like this:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ListaAgendaReceita}" Background="DimGray" SelectionMode="None">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Valor, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource CVTStringTODecimal}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Background="LightGray">
                <interact:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="TextChanged">
                        <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ElementName=usr_Receita, Path=DataContext.ModificacaoAgendaReceita}" 
                                                  CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                    </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
                </interact:Interaction.Behaviors>
            </TextBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
<ListView/>
```

EDIT.: this TextBox is part of a DataTemplate inside a ListView. I've edited the code block to mirror that more clearly. I'm also providing the same example but for the CalendarDatePicker, which **always fails** to send the model as a commandparameter, sending the eventargs instead.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ListaAgendaReceita}" Background="DimGray" SelectionMode="None">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CalendarDatePicker BorderThickness="0,3,0,1" DateFormat="{}{day.integer}/{month.integer}/{year.full}"
                                Date="{Binding Data, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource CVTDateTimeTODateTimeOffsetTwoWay}}"
                                BorderBrush="Green" Background="DarkGray">
                <interact:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="DateChanged">
                        <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ElementName=usr_Receita, Path=DataContext.ModificacaoAgendaReceita}"
                                                  CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                    </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
                </interact:Interaction.Behaviors>
            </CalendarDatePicker>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
<ListView/>
```

CVTDateTimeTODateTimeOffsetTwoWay is a simple Converter that treats the DateProperty, converting from DateTime to DateTimeOffset and vice-versa.

```
public class CVTDateTimeTODateTimeOffsetTwoWay : IValueConverter
{

    public object Convert(object value, Type TargetType, object parameter, string culture)
    {
        var Data = (DateTime)value;
        DateTime date = new DateTime(Data.Year, Data.Month, Data.Day, Data.Hour, Data.Minute, 0);

        return new DateTimeOffset(date);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type TargetType, object parameter, string culture)
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            DateTimeOffset dto = (DateTimeOffset)value;
            return new DateTime(dto.DateTime.Year, dto.DateTime.Month, dto.DateTime.Day, dto.DateTime.Hour, dto.DateTime.Minute, 0);
        }
        else return new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, DateTime.Today.Month, DateTime.Today.Day, 0, 0, 0);
    }

}
```

Since the TextBox is inside a ListView, the `CommandParameter="{Binding}"` should be the `ModelAgendaReceita`, which's the model that feeds the ListView's ItemsSource. The Event to Command keeps passing the TextChangedEventArgs as the CommandParameter, and I want the Model.

EDIT.: Here's an snippet of the Model:

```
public class ModelAgendaReceita : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public ModelAgendaReceita()
    {
    }

    //Here I create the model based on another model
    public ModelAgendaReceita(ModelAgendaReceita p_agendareceita)
    {
        ID = p_agendareceita.ID;
        IDFormaReceita = p_agendareceita.IDFormaReceita;
        Data = p_agendareceita.Data;
        Valor = p_agendareceita.Valor;
        Parcela = p_agendareceita.Parcela;
        Recibo = p_agendareceita.Recibo;
        Pago = p_agendareceita.Pago;
        DataPagamento = p_agendareceita.DataPagamento;
        Ativo = p_agendareceita.Ativo;
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }

    public int IDFormaReceita { get; set; }

    private DateTime m_data = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, DateTime.Today.Month, DateTime.Today.Day, 0, 0, 0);
    public DateTime Data
    {
        get { return m_data; }
        set { m_data = value; OnPropertyChanged("Data"); }
    }

    private decimal m_valor;
    public decimal Valor
    {
        get { return m_valor; }
        set { m_valor = value; OnPropertyChanged("Valor"); }
    }

    private int m_parcela;
    public int Parcela
    {
        get { return m_parcela; }
        set { m_parcela = value; OnPropertyChanged("Parcela"); }
    }

    private string m_recibo = string.Empty;
    public string Recibo
    {
        get { return m_recibo; }
        set { m_recibo = value; OnPropertyChanged("Recibo"); }
    }

    private bool m_pago = false;
    public bool Pago
    {
        get { return m_pago; }
        set { m_pago = value; OnPropertyChanged("Pago"); }
    }

    private DateTime m_datapagamento = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, DateTime.Today.Month, DateTime.Today.Day, 0, 0, 0);
    public DateTime DataPagamento
    {
        get { return m_datapagamento; }
        set { m_datapagamento = value; OnPropertyChanged("DataPagamento"); }
    }

    private bool m_ativo = true;
    public bool Ativo
    {
        get { return m_ativo; }
        set { m_ativo = value; OnPropertyChanged("Ativo"); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var changed = PropertyChanged;
        if (changed != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Here's how I declare my ViewModel and the Command inside it:

```
public class HomeVM
{
    public DelegateCommand SelecaoSolicitacao { get; set; }

    public HomeVM()
    {
        SelecaoSolicitacao = new DelegateCommand(SelecionarSolicitacao);
    }

    public void ModificarAgendaReceita(object obj)
    {
        var p_atual = (ModelAgendaReceita)obj;
        var p_inicial = ListaAgendaReceitaInicial.FirstOrDefault(l => l.ID == p_atual.ID);

        if (p_inicial != null) p_atual.Status = ModelAgendaReceita.ValidarAlteracao(p_inicial, p_atual);
    }
}
```

This is the class that I make my Commands with:

```
public class DelegateCommand : ICommand
{

    //These delegates store methods to be called that contains the body of the Execute and CanExecue methods
    //for each particular instance of DelegateCommand.
    private readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;
    private readonly Action<object> _Execute;

    //Two Constructors, for convenience and clean code - often you won't need CanExecute
    public DelegateCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
    {
        _canExecute = canExecute;
        _Execute = execute;
    }

    public DelegateCommand(Action<object> execute)
      : this(execute, null)
    { }

    //CanExecute and Execute come from ICommand
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute == null ? true : _canExecute(parameter);
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        if (!CanExecute(parameter))
            return;

        _Execute(parameter);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Not a part of ICommand, but commonly added so you can trigger a manual refresh on the result of CanExecute.
    /// </summary>
    public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
    {
        CanExecuteChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

}
```

Which I've followed from https://onewindowsdev.com/2016/06/16/the-command-pattern-and-mvvm/.

Does anyone know how to work around this? Any advice/help would be appreciated!

Comment: Could you post a bit more context about the issue? Is this Textbox is a part of a `DataTemplate`? What is the model used in your backend collection?

Comment: Like @PéterCsajtai said, your above code snippets were not enough, please provide a [mcve]. Then, we could help you diagnose this issue.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I've provided some more information. I might've forgotten something, please ask if need be.

Comment: You specified `ElementName=usr_Receita`, but where's the 'usr_Receita' on the XAML page?